# Performing a text classification based on a dictionary

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, data-science-model, text-classification

I have been given a kind of dictionary which maps a category with a set of certain strings. A sample of the dictionary is given below:

[image]

This is all I have, there is no other data. There are around 46 categories (DT5 Category) and in the similar way all categories have a few keywords associated with them.

Now I am supposed to create a model which takes any kind of text input most probably a customer review/query and my model should correctly classify it according to the keywords present in it (The keywords can be in other forms like different forms of verb etc.)
The model should state which category does it belong to. (Basically need an NLP based approach)

I am completely unable to understand, what model to use in this, what data should I test or train my model on. Considering this data, it has 46 classes and the data set is so small. Please help me regarding what approach should I use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

As defined, there's no ML in this problem: the program would associate each keyword to a category, so it would consist of a loop over the words in the documents, and inside the loop there is an if statement:

```
for every word in doc
   if associated_category[word] is defined then
       return associated_category[word]
```

That's it, this is the full rule-based classifier.

But this would not be a good system of course. Two of the main issues are:

- Some queries/documents may contain several keywords, for example "eta" and "destination". In this case the category is ambiguous.
- Some queries/documents may not contain any of the keywords. For example "What happened to my parcel?" should clearly be a `delivery_issue`, but doesn't contain any of the keywords.

So the problem as defined is not well specified, this will lead to ambiguities and errors.